# SELECT DISTINCT with Duplication check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees_Dim] ([EmpNo], [EmpName])
SELECT DISTINCT st.[EmpNo], [EmpName]
FROM [dbo].[EEMasterData] st
```

I want to take two columns out of a master table to create an Employee Dimension. 
(this will be duplicated for other dimensions coming from this master table).

I want to be able to run the script in an SSIS package that will look at the master data, reference the Employee_Dim and only add new employees based on their Employee Number.

I know I'm missing something just don't know what.

Update: The question I have is, What should I add to the above Script that would Insert only the newly added employees from the EEMasterData table into the EmployeeDim using the EmpNo as the Key.

Comment: Neither do we :) So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I was rushing to add this in. I updated the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... and only add new employees ...

If that is the issue you are facing, select only those entries which *do not already exist* in your dimension table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees_Dim] ([EmpNo], [EmpName])
SELECT DISTINCT st.[EmpNo], [EmpName]
FROM [dbo].[EEMasterData] st
WHERE st.[EmpNo] NOT IN (SELECT EmpNo FROM Employees_Dim)
```

(assuming that EmpNo is unique for each employee)

Comment: Correct, the EmpNo is unique to each employee. I will try this, I think this is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: it is faster to do `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employees_Dim edim WHERE edim.EmpNo = st.EmpNo)` if you're using SQL Server 2008 and greater (maybe 2005, also).

Comment: @tommy_o: Are you sure (= have you measured this)? If neither Employees_Dim.EmpNo nor st.EmpNo are nullable, the two versions are semantically equivalent. So why should the query optimizer choose different execution plans for them?

Comment: @Heinzi: Yes, in our practice we've seen measurable improvements, especially with large data.  And while it is possible for it to become equivalent under certain conditions, choosing `NOT EXISTS` will nearly always be more performant if the query is or becomes more complex; values change; etc.  For a dim, it probably doesn't matter either way :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: Ah, also I'm assuming st.EmpNo may be NULL.  The OP doesn't state that is not nullable, and I don't know what the dbo.EEMasterData table contains.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of info. The EmpNo is Not Null and the EEMasterData houses info like the Employee Name, Job Title, Cost Centers, etc.